# OpenVMS timer precision, better than millisecond accuracy.

Tags: c, performance, openvms, benchmarking

I'm wondering which function offers best precision/accuracy for timing on OpenVMS in C.

We have an HP Integrity rx2660 server running OpenVMS V8.3-1H1.

My search so far points to $GETTIM_PREC which offers 100-nano resolution but millisecond accuracy. 
Does it get any better than this?

regards

Answer (score 1):

From the [System Services Reference Manual](http://h30266.www3.hp.com/odl/axpos/opsys/vmsos84/4527/4527pro_067.html):

> On Integrity servers, $GETTIM_PREC returns the system time after
>   accounting for the time elapsed since the last one millisecond update
>   of the system time.
>
> On Alpha, this service is equivalent to $GETTIM service and just
>   returns the last updated system time. The successful completion status
>   of the service on ALPHA is SS$_LOWPREC.

So on Integrity it may be better than 1ms accuracy, but there doesn't seem to be a commitment to any particular accuracy.

`EXE$GL_ABSTIM_TICS` only provided accuracy to 10ms.  I don't know of any other internal values that are more accurate and haven't stumbled across an IDSM for V8.